When to use Google App Script createTemplateFromFile vs createHtmlOutputFromFile
I'm getting up to speed on Google App Script and want to build a custom dialog.  But I'm having a hard time getting my head around the differences between createHtmlOutputFromFile and createTemplateFromFile.  When using createTemplateFromFile, you need to run evaluate() which will then give you an HtmlOutput, the same return type as createHtmlOutputFromFile.  So, clearly, templates are an intermediate format that offer... something?  But what exactly is it good for?

Please refer to https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/templates.

createTemplateFromFile vs createHtmlOutputFromFile
createHtmlOutputFromFile Directly renders an HTML file without any preprocessing some usage is great for static HTML content that doesn’t need to change based on server-side data or logic.
Sample script
var output = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('myPage');

while
createTemplateFromFile generates a Template object, allowing you to add dynamic data or logic in the HTML some of the usage is when you need to inject server-side variables, conditionals, or loops directly into your HTML.
Sample script
var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('myTemplate');

Reference

createHtmlOutputFromFile

createTemplateFromFile



Hi, it will be great if someone can explain if the answer provided needs improvement or why it was downvoted. Thanks!
